# How to programmatically add buttons to a layout that don't stack on top of each other?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a layout that populates itself with buttons defined in a JSONObject in the file `buttons.txt`.  Generating the buttons from the file works but the problem is the buttons are all stacking on top of each other.  I've tried adding different LayoutParams to the buttons but only the params that define the relation to the layout itself seem to work, and none that alter the relationship with other child views.  How can I get the buttons into the "flow" of the layout?

```
private void createButtons(RelativeLayout layout, JSONObject jo, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp){

        Iterator<?> keys = jo.keys();

        while( keys.hasNext() ) {
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            Button newButton = new Button(this);
            newButton.setText(key);
            layout.addView(newButton, lp);

            JSONObject subCat = null;

            try {
                subCat = jo.getJSONObject(key);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                subCat = null;
            }

            if ( subCat instanceof JSONObject ) {
                createButtons(layout, (JSONObject) subCat, lp);
            }
        }
    }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(111, 111);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);

    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open("buttons.txt");
        json = readFully(is, "utf-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject jo = null;
    try {
        jo = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    createButtons(rl, jo, lp);
}
```

Comment: Why dont you add buttons in linear layout with horizontal orientation?

Comment: I just changed the layout to a LinearLayout and replaced all the RelativeLayout's with linear ones.  But now the buttons don't get added at all, and no error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving all the buttons the same layout params in the relative layout, which will stack them.  Try to add them to a linear layout which will add them sequentially.  You can apply centering to linear layouts also, but they won't stack.

Comment: And you can nest a linear layout within a scroll or relative layout if you need other features on the page to be dimensioned with the relative layout functionality

Comment: Yes, they all have the same layout params but if they describe how the buttons interact with other child views, why would that be a problem?  Maybe there are default values in the layout params object that are causing this behavior?  I will look into that.

Comment: Any idea why when I switch from Relative to LinearLayout the buttons don't show up at all?  The two functions and the layout are exactly the same except switched to LinearLayout.  No error gets thrown, just no buttons.

Comment: I used a new LinearLayout instead of an xml created one and it generates the buttons now.  Not sure why using the xml layout didn't work.